# Setting the product status disabled not working in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product

In Magento 2, I am trying to set the product Status as `Disabled`. But, it is not working. Here is the code.

```
$product = $this->objectManager->create ( 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product' )->load ( $productId );
           if($product->getImage () || $product->getSmallImage () || $product->getThumbnail ()){
                $product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
           }else if($product->getImage () || $product->getSmallImage () || $product->getThumbnail ()){
               $product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
           }
$product->save ();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$productIds = ['1','2','3'];
$storeId = 1;
$attributesData["status"] = 2;
$this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action')->updateAttributes($productIds, $attributesData, $storeId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You not should use `ObjectManager` , better way use `Repository`

Declare a dependency on it by adding it to your constructor

```
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

Then you can update the status and save it back with the following code in your method

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
$product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```